# Enable HTTP Method POST for a specific script on a shared hosting

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, curl

Hello everybody I need to update some datas on a script placed on a shared hosting.

both scripts, access and destination are PHP files.

I need to access the external file trough a post operation, but server is responding me "501 Method not implemented "

I have tried also to put on top of the receiving file

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

But I don't solve it as probably is nginx the same stopping it before the php file is executed.

How could I tell nginx or apache to enable post only for this file ?

Thanks everybuddy

Comment: Please post the code you are using to access the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx limit_except directive can restrict your script to only post requests -
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#limit_except

```
location /postzone {
  limit_except POST {
    deny   all;
  }
}
```

This would give a 403 for anything other than POST, not a 501. So they must be doing something else.

As you say, PHP can do nothing about this. If your host is blocking post requests they probably have a good reason, so I'd ask them.